# CPU profiling with web browser

Tags: javascript, cpu-usage, google-chrome-devtools

I have a static webpage generated with a Ruby script. It uses CSS, Javascript and jQuery. When I rapidly click on some buttons in the page that are connected to jQuery events, the CPU usage goes nearly 100%. I want to see the cause of the high CPU usage, and tried Google Chrome CPU profiler, and got the following shot:

[image: CPU profile]

The high CPU seems to be caused by what is described as `(program)`. What does that mean? And, is there a way to break down the `(program)` part to see in more detail which of my functions are using up the CPU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(program)` means either (a) the tab idle time, or (b) the native browser code executed. I guess your case is (b). Have a closer look at the `Timeline`, and if "Recalcualte Style" and "Paint" take up considerable time, you need to optimize your page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better to use Timeline tab. You can analyze CPU usage and it's easy for you.

Comment: I just tried it, but it just has a few items called "Recalculate Style", "Paint", etc. and I cannot see which particular functions are using the CPU time.